# urequests ValueError: invalid syntax for integer with base 10

Tags: http, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Code on Raspberry Pi Pico W:

```
SSID = "abcdefg"
PASSWORD = "123456"

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(SSID, PASSWORD)

print(wlan.isconnected())

response = urequests.get("http://username:password@10.10.100.254/status.html")
print(response)
```

I want the Raspberry Pi Pico to get status.html from an LSW-3 stick logger by solar man. It connects to Wi-Fi. GET request returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 180, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 74, in request
ValueError: invalid syntax for integer with base 10
```

URL works in browser when the computer is connected to the stick logger's Wi-Fi.

Comment: I suspect that username and password in URL giving you issues. Try to access page that is not secured. Computer browser is making many things under-the-hood (like handling BasicAuthentication protected requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
import network
import socket

SSID = "ssid"
PASSWORD = "password"

socketObject = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)

if wlan.isconnected():

    request = "GET /status.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 10.10.100.254\r\nAuthorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=\r\n\r\n"

    socketObject.connect(socket.getaddrinfo('10.10.100.254', 80)[0][-1])
    socketObject.send(request)

    print(socketObject.readline())
    print(socketObject.readline())
    print(socketObject.readline())

    data = socketObject.recv(512)
    print(data)

    socketObject.close()
```

dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ= is username:password in base64

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Python
[source](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/python-ecosys/urequests/urequests.py#L74),
assuming this corresponds to what you are calling, it seems that the url is
only expected to be for example `http://hostname:port/...`, so you cannot
put `user:pw@host` in there. Instead, further up the function we can see a
username and password being handled from the `auth` keyword parameter to
`.request()`. So try calling with

```py
.get("http://10.10.100.254/status.html",auth=("username","password"))
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I get ECONNABORTED.